# No Content-type in the header! Error while trying to access my Web Service

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, jboss

I am working on a Web Service example on eclipse using the jboss 4.2 server. I have Created a service implementation class as below:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService
public class CarWebServiceImpl  {

    private final Map<String, Integer> prices = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    public CarWebServiceImpl() {
        prices.put("audi", Integer.valueOf(10000));
        prices.put("bmw", Integer.valueOf(150000));
        prices.put("fiat", Integer.valueOf(5000));
    }

    @WebMethod
    public Response getCarPrice(String carId) {
        int price = prices.get(carId);
        Response resp = new Response();
        resp.setPrice(price);
        return resp;
    }

}
```

The Web Service is automatically deployed into the server and i can see my service at

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/jbossws/services/
```

I have created another project and have use the wsconsume utility to generate the client side class file. Then I instantiated the service class as follow:

```
public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CarWebServiceImplService service = new CarWebServiceImplService();
        CarWebServiceImpl port = service.getCarWebServiceImplPort();
        port.getCarPrice("audi");
    }
}
```

But when i am trying to run client code I am getting the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: No Content-type in the header!
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(HttpTransportPipe.java:172)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.processRequest(HttpTransportPipe.java:83)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.DeferredTransportPipe.processRequest(DeferredTransportPipe.java:105)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:587)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:546)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:531)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:428)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:211)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java:124)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:98)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:78)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:107)
    at $Proxy25.getCarPrice(Unknown Source)
    at wsclient.Client.main(Client.java:7)
```

I don't know what is wrong with my approach. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the fully qualified type name of Response?  It mentions that Content-type is not specified--have you tried setting it?

Comment: how do u set a response?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out that a few of the jar were missing in the JBoss's endorsed folder.

```
jbossws-jaxws.jar
jbossws-jaxws-ext.jar
jbossws-jaxrpc.jar
jbossws-saaj.jar
```

I moved these jars to /lib/endorsed from /client and restarted the server and the code worked without flaw.

Answer (score 0):

It's also possible that you use wrong version of SOAP:

- SOAP 1.1 uses text/xml
- SOAP 1.2 uses application/soap+xml

It happens when one component of your setup is sending SOAP 1.1 while the other is expecting SOAP 1.2 or inverse.

Ex: If you want to use SOAP 1.2

Add binding tag in enpoint declaration of sun-jaxws.xml, something like

```
<endpoint
    name="Authenticate"
    interface="com.xyz.interface"        
    implementation="com.xyz.interfaceimpl"
    binding="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws/2003/05/soap/bindings/HTTP/"
    url-pattern="/xyz/abc/service" />
```

Hope this help :)